# How does the 'dbchoice' function from the 'DCchoice' package calculate the mean and median WTP?

Tags: r

I am seeking clarity on how the 'dbchoice' function from the 'DCchoice' package calculates mean and median WTP in R.

I am using the function's default log-logistic distribution. According to Aizaki et al. (2014), the mean and median WTP is then calculated in R using the formulae in the attached image ([attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeWj5.png)). I have manually confirmed R's calculation of the median WTP using the constant and the bid coefficient from my restricted model (i.e., exp(-constant/bid)). However, I am not sure how to manually confirm the mean WTP.

If anyone can shed any light on what's going on under the hood here, I would really appreciate it!

Kind regards.

Reference: Aizaki, H., Nakatani, T. Sato, K. 2014, Stated preference methods using R, CRC Press, Florida.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - there's the source for that function: https://rdrr.io/cran/DCchoice/src/R/dbchoice.R

Comment: And here https://rdrr.io/cran/DCchoice/src/R/wtp.R is the source for the `wtp()` function in the same package - you can see the method depends on the distribution as expected and includes `meanWTP <- integrate(func, 0, Inf, stop.on.error = FALSE)$value` for lognormal